# ResourcesNotFoundException when initialising Drawable

Tags: android, drawable

```
private Drawable drawable;

drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
```

When I run this on my htc desire it goes, but on emulator it crashes when I try to initialiser drawable. Why is this?

edit: here is my stacktrace

```
  03-28 13:27:58.453: ERROR/ActivityThread(888): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
03-28 13:28:06.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.test.helloworld/be.test.helloworld.MyMapActivityII}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:846)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:534)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at be.test.helloworld.MyMapActivityII.initOverlays(MyMapActivityII.java:44)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at be.test.helloworld.MyMapActivityII.onCreate(MyMapActivityII.java:38)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
03-28 13:28:06.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(888):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try to refresh your project.. it's worth a try.

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: and the icon is also in just 'drawable'-folder. Can you also put you stacktrace?

Comment: Use this code : 
Drawable d;
d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

Comment: You are getting error even after using the above code ?

Comment: Then it crashes on Drawable d; ...

Comment: could it be that you import import android.R; instead of import be.capptain.helloworld.R?!

Comment: please clean your project once ...

Comment: @Mur votema: when I ctrl-click on r it goes to the be.capptain.helloworld.R class so that's not it

@Chirag:clean build doesn't help

Comment: @chirag but why the code runs on device?

Comment: @vincent sometimes it helps not only to clean a project but also to delete the gen-folder

Comment: Do I need to declare R.drawable.icon in the manifest too? Can't find the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an icon in all of the drawable folders (drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi)

Comment: It is not necessary that icon must be in all the three folders..not true...It must be present in any one of the folder..

Comment: I think, i had a crash once, because one pic wasn't in one of the folders. But i'm not sure

Comment: It does not need to be in every folder per say, if android can't find the drawable in the correct folder it defaults to the standard drawable folder, if its not there then you will have problems.